# Question about centralizer and groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $a$ be an element of the group $G$, and define its centralizer as $$C(a)=\left\{x \in G : a*x=x*a \right\}$$

We already know that $C(a)$ defines a subgroup of $G$ but I'm supposed to prove that $C(a) = C(a^3)$ if $o(a)=5$ where $o(a)$ denotes the order of the element $a$. I feel that my solution is not correct because I have not used the information $o(a)=5$, can anyone help me or point out mistakes in my proof?

Now suppose $y \in c(a)$, we will prove that then $y \in c(a^3)$. It is obvious that $a \in c(a)$, furthermore since $c(a)$ is a group we must have $y*a \in c(a)$. So we have: $$(y*a)*a = a*(y*a) \implies y*a^2 =a^2*y$$ Where we have used that $*$ is a binary associative operation and that $y \in c(a)$. So we now have that $y \in c(a^2)$. We will just repeat the argument now, by saying that $a^2 \in c(a)$ (this is obvious) so then $y*a^2 \in c(a)$

have: $$(y*a^2)*a = a*(y*a^2) \implies y*a^3=a^3*y$$
Where we have used that $*$ is a binary operation (and hence associative) and we have used that $y \in c(a^2)$ and hence $y \in c(a^3)$

As i said, i have not used the fact that $o(a) = 5$ which worries me, is my proof correct or have i missed something?

Answer (score 2):

This is all correct, but you haven't done the converse inclusion: $c(a^3)\subset c(a)$. There you won't be able to "tack on" one $a$ at a time, and this is where $o(a)=5$ is vitally important.

Comment: I had, for some reason, missed the inverse. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Since $o(a) = 5$, there is a power of $a^3$ that equals $a$. Use this to complete your proof by showing the inclusion $C(a^3) \subset C(a)$.